# Is it possible to determine if a LinqToSql context was disposed?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I found no way to determine if a context was disposed or not because it isn't set to null and it doesn't have a State property or something.

Comment: why and where do you need to know it? can you show your failing code?

Comment: Frankly, there's something wrong with your design if you have a context in your possession that you don't know whether or not it's disposed.

Comment: A code example here would be splendid.  Generally an object isn't going to be disposed unless it went out of scope or was explicitly disposed.  Either way, there's likely a bigger problem with your architecture if this is a concern (as mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

If you Dispose your DataContext this way...

```
using (CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext())
{
  //use myDC to do something
}
```

The variable referencing the datacontext instance goes out of scope at the same time as the instance is disposed - which means you don't have to keep track.